# Applying Reduce[] to a table

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions, list-manipulation

I have a table for example:

`t = Table[k,{k,5}]`

which returns

> {1,2,3,4,5}

and for every element in this table I want to check when it is $\leq 1 + a$.

I used the Reduce commend as `Reduce[t<1+f,f]` but it doesn't work. How can I do that, without writing all inequalities separately ?

Comment: Look at [Map](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Map.html).

Comment: Do you want all those inequalities to hold simultaneously?

Comment: @belisarius Yes

Comment: Then look at the Edit in my answer

Answer (score 1):

```
Thread[Array[# &, 5] <= 1 + a]
(*
 {1 <= 1 + a, 2 <= 1 + a, 3 <= 1 + a, 4 <= 1 + a, 5 <= 1 + a}
*)
```

**Edit**

Probably you want something like

```
t = Table [k, {k,5}];
Reduce[And @@ Thread[t  <= 1 + a], a]
(*
a >= 4
*)
```

But I'm not quite sure

Comment: Or Range[] or Table[] instead of Array[]

Comment: the table which I wrote was only a suggestion. I want to reduce a table of values which have very different valueslike 0.0005,0.678,0.98999,1,456. And in your solution, can I do something like this? And I want to hold all those inequalities simultaneously

Comment: @Ziva Yes. Take a look at the EDIT

Answer (score 0):

```
f[a_] := Map[Reduce[# <= a] &, Table[k, {k, 5}]]

f[3]

{True, True, True, False, False}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is to check whether something (x) is less than 1+a. A simple approach is to make this a function:

```
f[x_, a_] := x < 1 + a
```

Now you can observe that f[10,6] is False and f[10,11] is True. Too apply this to a long list, use Map:

```
list = Range[10];
f[#, 3] & /@ list
{True, True, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False}
```

The abbreviated form f[#, 3] & /@ list is short for the `Map` function.